# Can I put the type of a field in Elasticsearch to be both ip and ip_range?

Tags: elasticsearch, types, ip, range, field

I am new to Elasticsearch and I am trying to index documents which have a field of type IP as below:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "sourceIp": {
        "type": "ip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is that if I could map the sourceIp to take both ip and ip ranges as values?

I tried the multi_field as below:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "sourceIp": {
        "type": "ip"
      },
      "fields": {
        "ip1": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "ip2": {
          "type": "ip_range"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it did not work.
Can anyone please give me a way to solve that?

Thanks.

Comment: May I ask you what did you try after changing the mapping? Did you try to index new documents, and Elasticsearch didn't manage to do it? Or did you update the existing index, without re-indexing the documents? This will help to clarify the problem.

Comment: Actually I deleted the index and created a new one with the new mapping, it is just an experiment so I can delete and create indices as much as I want

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to copy the ip field into a second field, let's say the second field is called `sourceIpRange`. Then, you have 2 fields and you can assign different type for each.

In order to copy the field you can either do it before indexing to ES, i.e. in logstash, or use Elasticsearch Ingest set processor: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/set-processor.html